# Remove the ugly borders and set different colors to hyperlinks using elsarticle template

Tags: hyperref, elsarticle

I am using the `elsarticle` template to write something. I want to remove the ugly border and use different colors instead. 
My setting is as follows:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red,citecolor=green]{hyperref}
```

The results is that ugly borders disappear but the all of `linkcolor` and `citecolor` are blue despite of no blue setting.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Class `elsarticle` also sets the colors:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}
  {\def\@linkcolor{blue}
   \def\@anchorcolor{blue}
   \def\@citecolor{blue}
   \def\@filecolor{blue}
   \def\@urlcolor{blue}
   \def\@menucolor{blue}
   \def\@pagecolor{blue}
```

Therefore your colors should be set at a later time:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \hypersetup{%
    linkcolor=red,%
    citecolor=green,%
  }%
}%
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The second component of your provided code works well. BTW, what is the first component used for? (above the sentence "Therefore your colors should be set at a later time:")

Comment: @user22986: The "first component" is just the code snipset of `elsarticle.cls`, proving that the class is responsible for the blue color and shows the time, when the colors are set (`\AtBeginDocument`).

Comment: @Hiko: you not only told me how to do it but also leave the reason. Thanks very much!